# Adjacency Matrix from Numpy array using Euclidean Distance

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, euclidean-distance, adjacency-matrix

Can someone help me please on how to generate a weighted adjacency matrix from a numpy array based on euclidean distance between all rows, i.e 0 and 1, 0 and 2,.. 1 and 2,...?

Given the following example with an input matrix(5, 4):

```
matrix = [[2,10,9,6],
          [5,1,4,7],
          [3,2,1,0], 
          [10, 20, 1, 4], 
          [17, 3, 5, 18]]
```

I would like to obtain a weighted adjacency matrix (5,5) containing the most minimal distance between nodes, i.e,

```
if dist(row0, row1)= 10,77 and dist(row0, row2)= 12,84, 

--> the output matrix will take the first distance as a column value.
```

I have already solved the first part for the generation of the adjacency matrix with the following code :

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dist = cdist( matrix, matrix, metric='euclidean')
```

and I get the following result :

```
array([[ 0.        , 10.77032961, 12.84523258, 15.23154621, 20.83266666],
       [10.77032961,  0.        ,  7.93725393, 20.09975124, 16.43167673],
       [12.84523258,  7.93725393,  0.        , 19.72308292, 23.17326045],
       [15.23154621, 20.09975124, 19.72308292,  0.        , 23.4520788 ],
       [20.83266666, 16.43167673, 23.17326045, 23.4520788 ,  0.        ]])
```

But I don't know yet how to specify the number of neighbors for which we select for example 2 neighbors for each node. For example, we define the number of neighbors N = 2, then for each row, we choose only two neighbors with the two minimum distances and we get as a result :

```
[[ 0.        , 10.77032961, 12.84523258, 0, 0],
       [10.77032961,  0.        ,  7.93725393, 0, 0],
       [12.84523258,  7.93725393,  0.        , 0, 0],
       [15.23154621, 0, 19.72308292,  0.        , 0 ],
       [20.83266666, 16.43167673, 0, 0 ,  0.        ]]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you consider a node? is it a row? what is the desired adjacency matrix output for your example input?

Comment: Hello Ehsan, Thank you for your interest, yes i meant row by node.  I have already updated the publication.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. Please check to see if suggested answer resolves your issue.

Comment: Check my solution with `np.argsort` and `np.where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this cleaner solution to get the smallest n from a matrix. Try the following -

The `dist.argsort(1).argsort(1)` creates a rank order (smallest is 0 and largest is 4) over axis=1 and the <= 2 decided the number of nsmallest values you need from the rank order. `np.where` filters it or replaces it with 0.

```
np.where(dist.argsort(1).argsort(1) <= 2, dist, 0)
```

```
array([[ 0.        , 10.77032961, 12.84523258,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [10.77032961,  0.        ,  7.93725393,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [12.84523258,  7.93725393,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [15.23154621,  0.        , 19.72308292,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [20.83266666, 16.43167673,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

This works for any axis or if you want nlargest or nsmallest from a matrix as well.

Comment: Hello Akshay, i tried it and it worked, thank you for providing me with another solution with enough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` is your Euclidean distance matrix, you can use `np.argpartition` to choose `n` min/max values per row. Keep in mind the diagonal is always 0 and euclidean distances are non-negative, so to keep two closest point in each row, you need to keep three min per row (including 0s on diagonal). This does not hold if you want to do max however.

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],np.argpartition(a, 3, axis=1)[:,3:]] = 0
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.        , 10.77032961, 12.84523258,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [10.77032961,  0.        ,  7.93725393,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [12.84523258,  7.93725393,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [15.23154621,  0.        , 19.72308292,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [20.83266666, 16.43167673,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, i really appreciate your help.